# How to use log4j in my project? Advantages of logback over log4j?

Tags: java, servlets, log4j, logback

How do I implement and use log4j/logback in my JSP/Servlet project? What is the advantage of using logback over log4j?

Comment: Please don't repeat the same questions. You already asked about advantages here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4516932/difference-between-slf4j-and-log4j

Answer (score 3, accepted):

log4j has a very good documentation on its site. Just start from [here](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/manual.html).

EDIT:

In a JSP/Servlet project:

1. Add log4j.jar into your WEB-INF/lib directory.
2. Add log4j.properties into the WEB-INF/classes directory.
3. Use it in your code as described in the documentation above.

Answer (score 7):

> what is the advantage of using logback over log4j

This is what Ceki Gülcü the author of Log4j and Logback says about [logback's advantages](http://logback.qos.ch/reasonsToSwitch.html).

Since he is comparing his own products / projects, he is (at least) qualified to know.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you should peep [Logback](http://logback.qos.ch/) before!

Answer (score 0):

You can check this about [Log4J Understanding](http://harigm.blogspot.com/2010/02/log4j-vs-javautillogging.html)